# When using PyQt and PyDbus, how I do pass a map containing QDBusVariants to the D-Bus?

Tags: python, pyqt6, qdbus

I am having trouble calling a method to the D-Bus.  Check this code:

```
class DBusAdaptor(QDBusAbstractAdaptor):
    pyqtClassInfo('D-Bus Interface', 'org.pyqt.LinuxCleaner')
    pyqtClassInfo('D-Bus Path', '/LinuxCleaner')

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        connect = QDBusConnection.connectToBus(QDBusConnection.BusType.SessionBus, 'LinuxCleaner')
        conn_iface = connect.interface()
        if not connect.registerService('org.pyqt.LinuxCleaner'):
            print('Failed to register service')
        if not connect.registerObject('/LinuxCleaner', self):
            print('Failed to register Object!')
        print(connect.baseService())
        self._check_polkit_privilege(conn_iface, 'org.pyqt.LinuxCleaner')

    def _check_polkit_privilege(self, conn_iface, service):
        """
        :param conn_iface: D-Bus connection interface.
        :type conn_iface: QDBusConnectionInterface
        :param service: D-Bus service name.
        :type service: str
        :return:
        """
        pid = conn_iface.servicePid(service).value()
        interface = QDBusInterface('org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1',
                                   '/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority',
                                   'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority',
                                   QDBusConnection.systemBus())
        struct = QDBusArgument()
        struct.beginStructure()
        struct.add('unix-process', 10)
        struct.beginMap(10, 3)
        struct.beginMapEntry()
        struct.add('pid', 10)
        struct.add(pid, 3)
        struct.endMapEntry()
        struct.beginMapEntry()
        struct.add('start-time', 10)
        struct.add(0, 3)
        struct.endMapEntry()
        struct.endMap()
        struct.endStructure()
        struct.add('org.pyqt.LinuxCleaner.auth', 10)
        struct.beginMap(10, 10)
        struct.beginMapEntry()
        struct.add('AllowUserInteraction', 10)
        struct.add('true', 10)
        struct.endMapEntry()
        struct.endMap()
        struct.add(1, 3)
        struct.add('', 10)
        reply = interface.call('CheckAuthorization', struct)
        print(reply.errorMessage())
```

I get the following error message:
`Type of message, “((sa{su}))”, does not match expected type “((sa{sv})sa{ss}us)”`  I take that to mean that `{sv}` requires a QDBusVariant (according to Qt docs), yet `beginMap()` only accepts `QMetaType`'s as arguments.  `QDBusVariant` is not an exposed Meta Type.  How would I solve this?  How can I pass a `QDBusVariant` to `beginMap()`?  I can't, can I?

Comment: I certainly don't think so, and it is annoying the hell out of me.  As far as I can tell, it's impossible to send certain DBus messages using pyqt and QtDBus.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too.  QtDBus is somewhat limited.  Odd considering some Linux distro's use it for things.

Comment: In C++, you do this: 
    argument.beginMap (QVariant::String, qMetaTypeId<QDBusVariant>());  My C++ is super rusty, and I can't work out what "qMetaTypeId<QDBusVariant>()" translates to in Python (or if it even does).  If it was just a constant, it could be fudged, but the Qt source code leaves me no wiser.

Comment: It just seems totally brain dead.  I've tried to work around it by using python dbus with the DBusQtMainLoop, but that needs to all run in one thread, and using reply_handler just doesn't seem to work for me.   I'm absolutely tearing my hair out over this.

Comment: According to [The Qt D-Bus Type System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdbustypesystem.html) QDBusVariant is treated as a variant, and QMetaType offers the [`type()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmetatype.html#type) static function, which returns a valid and registered type for `QVariant`. I admit that I have not a lot of experience with QDBus (and I always thought that DBus in general was a mess), so what I'm writing could just be bulls**t, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Yep, that's the ticket!  Amazing!  I'll post an answer below.

Comment: Thanks for that.  This has literally been bugging me for weeks.

Answer (score 1):

The following code for PyQt5 creates a QDBusArgument of type "a{sv}" (a dict/map of string keys with DBusVariant values).

```
map = QDBusArgument()
map.beginMap(QMetaType.QString, QMetaType.type("QDBusVariant"))
map.beginMapEntry()
map.add("key")
map.add(QDBusVariant("value"))
map.endMapEntry()
map.endMap()
```

This requires the use of the type() method of QMetaType, about which the Qt6 docs say "This function is deprecated. We strongly advise against using it in new code".  QMetaType.fromName() may work instead on Qt6, but I have not tested this.

Comment: Note: depending on the Qt and PyQt version, using `QDBusVariant` may not work (for instance, in older [Py]Qt versions it is an unregistered type, so it will return an invalid type id. Using `QVariant` instead *should* work as expceted. Also, while `type()` is deprecated in Qt6, that version should be able to return a proper QMetaType based on the `fromName()` static function, which *could* lead to the proper [`id()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmetatype.html#id) (as said, I've not sufficient experience with QDBus, but I strongly suggest to do proper and reliable research about that).

Comment: Also, `type()` is *obsolete*: not completely deprecated; while the suggestion is "strongly [...] against" it doesn't mean that it's completely deprecated or unusable. As with most mid-release cases, careful implementation has to be considered. If valid alternatives are provided, then it should be advised, otherwise, it probably has to be considered as "work in progress" due to current underlying changes within the API. Which also means that any new API should be carefully considered as well, as it may be based on temporarily situations that may not be considered reliable for future releases.

Comment: @musicmante Thanks for that. I have updated the answer accordingly.  QVariant does not work, returning a QDBusMarshaller error about QVariant not being registered with D-Bus.